# Java implementations of SCIM

Tags: java, identity

SCIM is a fresh standard for user provisioning put forward by Google, Salesforce, Ping Identity..etc.. Are there existing java implementations to support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSO2 Charon is another java based SCIM implementation.

http://www.slideshare.net/HasiniG/wso2-charon

Comment: Is this SCIM 2.0 compliant?

Comment: Yes it is SCIM 2 compliant.

Answer (score 3):

Nice to hear that someone has found the scimproxy project since I´m one of the owners of that project.  However I know of at least two other Java projects that implements SCIM.

- [OpenSCIM](https://code.google.com/p/openscim/)
- UnboudID has a [SCIM SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/labs/scim.php)

Comment: Glad to hear from you.. I am an architect WSO2 and we are planning to add SCIM support for WSO2 Identity Server. You can see our cloud deployment @ https://stratoslive.wso2.com

Comment: The SCIM SDK link is broken.

Comment: Looks like UnboundID are no longer supporting this.

Comment: The UnboundID website underwent a redesign recently and it looks like this link was broken.  However, the SCIM SDK repository is currently hosted on Google Code (https://code.google.com/p/scimsdk/ although since Google Code is shutting down it will eventually be migrated to GitHub) and the artifacts are in the Maven Central Repository (http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.unboundid.product.scim)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the [UnboundID SCIM repository](https://github.com/pingidentity/scim2) is [still active](https://github.com/pingidentity/scim2/releases) and is hosted on github.

Answer (score 2):

Found a java implementation at its early stage supporting SCIM.

http://code.google.com/p/scimproxy/

Answer (score 2):

On the SCIM Homepage you can find a list of known implementations including their licences and links to the implementations:

http://www.simplecloud.info/ -> Implementations.

Answer (score 1):

A list of SCIM implementations is available on the SCIM wiki -

http://code.google.com/p/scim/wiki/Implementations

Answer (score 0):

another library supporting scim that is also feature complete and supports the whole set defined in the rfc's

https://github.com/Captain-P-Goldfish/SCIM-SDK