# SCIM 2.0 Java Server - Custom data store / Back End

Tags: apache, scim

We are looking at providing a SCIM 2.0 interface for our user json repository.

The below thread indicates there are some scim 1.1 implementations in Java, however we have been asked to be compliant with SCIM 2.0.
[Java implementations of SCIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287659/java-implementations-of-scim)

Looking at http://www.simplecloud.info, we find three available options, 
Apache eSCIMO
Kumiq Identity
OSIAM

We have looked at SCIMProxy 1.1 and it had examples of 2-3 back end data storage interfaces ( eg In Memory , Mongo DB ). However such examples or documentation is not available with 2.0 servers we have looked so far.

Would highly Appreciate if someone could provide pointers in terms of which one may be a better option to use ? Any specific pros / cons ?

Or if we can look at any other SCIM server ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late, but since SCIM is here to stay : [personify-scim-server](https://bitbucket.org/wouter29/personify-scim-server/src/master/) is a core implementation that can be customized with a custom storage layer.

It supports nearly everything.

For storage there is oob : ldap, mongo, MySQL and postgres.