# Ruby implementations of SCIM v2

Tags: ruby, identity

SCIM is a fresh standard for user provisioning put forward by Google, Salesforce, Ping Identity..etc.. Are there existing ruby implementations to support this?

[Similar but for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287659/java-implementations-of-scim)

Answer (score 1):

You can get an Okta-oriented start [from here](https://github.com/lessonly/scim_rails) or start from scratch [here](https://github.com/Cisco-AMP/scim_engine) but I think you're otherwise on your own.

Yay! You've got an opportunity to contribute an open source project to the Ruby community :)